# Trying to Update Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher

Tags: android-studio

I am prompted this error while trying to generate a Signed Bundle / APK.

[image]

When I click Update here nothing else happens.

[image]

Do you have any hint about what to do next ?

Comment: Something might be wrong with the Graphical User Interface of this Software Updater. Beside signing in and signing out again with the same User Account, rebooting the Machine and trying again the same things that you have already tried, I would be looking for an Alternative Solution for this Software Updater, including a Command-Line Version of it.